# Is there any way to set Inno Setup wizard font programmatically?

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to set `DialogFontName` in the `[LangOptions]` section from scripting code?

I've tried everything I can think of (including using a scripted constant), but since this directive doesn't expand constants, I can't see a way to do it.  Ditto with `DefaultDialogFontName` in the `Setup` section - that doesn't expand constants either.

Just for context, I want to use Segoe UI on everything but XP, where it doesn't exist (and yes, I still support XP, so I'm using Inno Setup 5.6.1).

Answer (score 0):

Hah, cracked it!  Here's how, if anyone else ever wants to know.

It was simple in the end, I just added:

```
{ Set our wizard font }
procedure InitializeWizard ();
var
    Font : TFont;
begin
    Font := WizardForm.Font;
    Font.Name := GetDialogFont ();
    WizardForm.Font := Font;
end;
```

Where `GetDialogFont`  is a function that returns the desired font name.

I continue to set `DialogFontSize` in the `[LangOptions]` section, but I'm sure you could set it programatically using this trick if you wanted to.

Comment: Well, if you just want to change the main wizard font (what you didn't say), then this will do. But it's not an equivalent of setting `DialogFontSize` programmatically, as the directive affects all installer windows, not just the main wizard window.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry, yes, XY problem.  And my only windows are wizard windows.

Comment: Are you sure? There are lot of dialogs that can popup in Inno Setup installers.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm new to Inno Setup, so not entirely, no.  Message boxes are still using MS Shell Dlg, 8 point (regardless of platform),for example, but that was true even when I was setting `DialogFontName`.  What else might I encounter?

Comment: Indeed, messages are probably rendered by the system, so they do not follow Inno Setup settings. But there are other windows: most important are the uninstaller, select directory and select language windows.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, I'll be on the lookout for those.  If push comes to shove, I'll stop being so OCD about perfect support for XP.